# mysql equivalent of limti x,y of mongodb through ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

I want to select y documents starting from x through ruby on rails application.There is a first(n) method in ruby but that obviously wont serve the purpose.I want a ruby equivalent of the following mongodb query

```
db.users.find().limit(5).skip(10)
```

Does there exist any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the topic [Active Record Query Interface - Limit and Offset](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset):

```
Users.limit(5).offset(10)
```